# Consider the linear system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Consider the linear system of differential equations: \begin{align}\frac{dx}{dt}= 
 \ \ \ \ \ x \ + \ y \\ \frac{dy}{dt}=-2x+4y \end{align}
**(a)** Solve the system and find the general solution. **(b)** Sketch  the phase portrait.

---

To solve the system I have found the eigen values of the asociated matrix which are $ \lambda=2,3$.

**Edit:** I now need only part **(b)** because I already solved part **(a)**. The general solution is given by $A e^{2t} \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}+B e^{3t} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$

Is there any help for me? Thank you.

Comment: The zero vector is always an eigenvector. But in order to calculate an eigenvector you have to solve $A\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix} = \lambda \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$ instead of $A\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=0$.

Comment: Also your matrix should be $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\-2&4\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: I get eigenvalues of 2 and 3.  An eigenvalue of -1 doesn't make the determinant of A-lambda*I equal zero!

Comment: Actually the eigen values are 3,2. I made wrong calculations. Can you please help me drawing phase portrait

Comment: So, do you need help for part **(a)** at all, or only part **(b)**?

Comment: I now need only part (b) because I already solved part (a) . The general solution is given by $ A e^{2t} \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}+B e^{3t} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} $

Comment: The phase portrait simply describes the regions of the $(x,y)$-plane where $x'=0$, where $y'=0$, where $x'>0$ and $y'>0$, where $x'>0$ and $y'<0$, where $x'<0$ and $y'>0$, and where $x'<0$ and $y'<0$. Why is it difficult to determine these regions and to draw them all on a single figure?

Comment: yes I figured out it. Thanks

Comment: @Wauzl, The zero vector $\vec0$ always satisfies $A\vec0 = \lambda\vec0$ but some texts (like the one I taught from last semester) require eigenvectors to be not the zero vector, so I'd be careful with saying "the zero vector is always an eigenvector."  AFAIK it's actually standard to require an eigenvector to be not $\vec0$.

Comment: @tilper you are right, I looked it up again. $\vec 0$ is by definition not an Eigenvector, but satisfies $A\vec 0 = \lambda \vec 0$ (for ALL $\lambda$, not only Eigenvalues) and is always part of all Eigenspaces.